# What is error CS0201 in C# program and how i fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, while-loop, game-development

```
public delegate void LoopCallback();
LoopCallback _callback;

public FastLoop(LoopCallback callback)
{
    _callback = callback;
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(OnApplicationEnterIdle);
}

void OnApplicationEnterIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (IsAppStillIdle())
    {
        _callback;  
    }
}
```

I am new to Game Development and I deal with this error:

```
"CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
```

I have tied to search it in the google and I can't understand what is this error for in order to fix on my own and I didn't find a working solution. Can you help me to fix it please?

Thanks!

Comment: ``_callback`` it's a simple variable, that have a type ``LoopCallback``, so inside while, what are you expected to do?

Comment: Are you meaning to *call* the `_callback` within the while loop? You call methods with parentheses, even if there are no arguments: `_callback()`.

Comment: @JoeSewell your comment is the answer.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help the problem solved ( it was a silly mistake to not put parentheses ). Also thanks @Sajid for your clarification.